# How do I get stage output in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This seems like an odd issue, because I'm unable to find any hints that other people are having the same problem - in fact there are more questions asked about *suppressing* output. So I'm probably missing something basic, but I'm not sure what it could be.

I have created a very basic build in Jenkins using the multi-branch pipeline. Jenkins is running in docker, and the build is running on the built-in node. The build successfully retrieves changed branches, finds the Jenkinsfile, and (seemingly) runs it. However, **no stage information or other output appears.**

Here is the relevant part of the console output:

```
...
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 27aea098fcacbbac2125d0aa18457b8612bcbb39
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The current pipeline is just copied from the jenkins documentation:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo 'This will always run'
        }
        success {
            echo 'This will run only if successful'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'This will run only if failed'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'
        }
        changed {
            echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'
            echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that this pipeline is actually the one being used (by introducing a syntax error and seeing that it fails). I have tried the shell command vs echo, e.g., `sh 'echo "Building.."'` - no change. I have tried using commands that return a non-zero error code - no change. I can't find anywhere that there might be a configuration option that would be suppressing the display.

Any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong, misunderstanding, or what I might be able to do to debug this?

Comment: You may want to confirm this is the actual `Jenkinsfile` being used.

Comment: It is. If I introduce a syntax error to the file, the build fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an explanation, but the problem went away by switching docker images. The problem was occurring with `bitnami/jenkins:2`, but it did not occur when using `jenkins/jenkins`.

I'd love to hear a reason why this happens, as I'm sure the bitnami jenkins works just fine, but switching definitely resolved our problem.